# Quick cursoring and replacement over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have an initial list which is partitioned as follows.

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
part = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}}
```

The partition puts element i of `data` in a sublist {i-1,i,i+1}, e.g. the fourth element in `data` (4) appears in the third, fourth and fifth elements in `part` in positions 3,2,1 respectively. I want to cursor across `part` and if a test suceeds I want to replace

1) the ith element in `data`
2) the elements in `part` that correspond to it

This code does what I want, with one error that does not affect me.

```
list := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
part := {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}}
func[{a_, b_, c_}] := (a + b + c)/3
func[{a_, b_}] := (a + b)/2
func[{b_, c_}] := (b + c)/2

Do[{Print[part[[i]]]; 
test = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[func[part[[i]]], 1]];
If[list[[i]] > test, {list = ReplacePart[list, i -> test];
part = ReplacePart[part, {{i - 1, 3} -> test, {i, 2} -> test, {i + 1, 1}-> test}]}, Nothing];
}, {i, 1, 8}]
part
list
```

To make things as clear as possible, I print the input to `test` and in the end I call the output. I use `SetDelayed` to store the updated lists in each step. The `Do` loop does not break for i=1, i=8, which is very useful.

> {1,2}
>
> {-0.149498,2,3}
>
> {2,3,4}
>
> {3,4,5}
>
> {3.64625,5,6}
>
> {3.69681,6,7}
>
> {6,7,8}
>
> {7,8}
>
> (*part output, as intended*)
>
> {{1, -0.149498}, {-0.149498, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3.64625}, {3, 3.64625, 
>     3.69681}, {3.64625, 3.69681, 6}, {3.69681, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 
>     7.7758}, {7, 7.7758}}
>
> (*list output, as intended*)
>
> {-0.149498, 2, 3, 3.64625, 3.69681, 6, 7, 7.7758}

The error is in the first element of `part`, which should be {-0.149498,2}. Since I won't be needing this I can live with the issue. The last element is updated correctly, on the other hand.

I keep the question about efficiency open. `Transpose` does not cover me because `part` must be updated in parallel with `list` (one step at a time), and `Table` constructs a new list every time which is time consuming (I use `ReplacePart` to avoid that). Because ReplacePart is slow, possible candidates are `MapAt`/ `Apply`, or even `NestList`.

Again, thank you all for your patience and good will. Hopefully this explains what I am aiming for, which is a dynamic sequence.

Comment: Large overhaul in OP.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** to do conditional replacements iteratively:

```
ClearAll[tstF, replaceAndPartition]
replaceAndPartition = Module[{d = #, p = partition@#, tf = #2}, 
  Table[d[[i]] = Min[d[[i]], tf[p[[i]]]]; p = partition[d]; {d, p}, {i, 1, Length@d}]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
tstF = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[Mean[#], 1]] &;
Grid[replaceAndPartition[data, tstF] /. x_Real :> Round[x, .01], 
  Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,4.58,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,4.58\},\{4,4.58,6\},\{4.58,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,4.58,5.85,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,4.58\},\{4,4.58,5.85\},\{4.58,5.85,7\},\{5.85,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,4.58,5.85,6.97,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,4.58\},\{4,4.58,5.85\},\{4.58,5.85,6.97\},\{5.85,6.97,8\},\{6.97,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,4.58,5.85,6.97,7.58\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,4.58\},\{4,4.58,5.85\},\{4.58,5.85,6.97\},\{5.85,6.97,7.58\},\{6.97,7.58\}\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

```
SeedRandom[1]
tf= Mean[#] + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}] &;
Grid[replaceAndPartition[data, tf] /. x_Real :> Round[x, .1], Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,4,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,3.7,5,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,3.7\},\{3,3.7,5\},\{3.7,5,6\},\{5,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,3.7,4.6,6,7,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,3.7\},\{3,3.7,4.6\},\{3.7,4.6,6\},\{4.6,6,7\},\{6,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,3.7,4.6,5.4,7,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,3.7\},\{3,3.7,4.6\},\{3.7,4.6,5.4\},\{4.6,5.4,7\},\{5.4,7,8\},\{7,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,3.7,4.6,5.4,6.9,8\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,3.7\},\{3,3.7,4.6\},\{3.7,4.6,5.4\},\{4.6,5.4,6.9\},\{5.4,6.9,8\},\{6.9,8\}\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1,1.6,3,3.7,4.6,5.4,6.9,7.2\} & \{\{1,1.6\},\{1,1.6,3\},\{1.6,3,3.7\},\{3,3.7,4.6\},\{3.7,4.6,5.4\},\{4.6,5.4,6.9\},\{5.4,6.9,7.2\},\{6.9,7.2\}\}
>    \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[partition]
partition = Partition[#, 3, 1, {-2, 2}, {}] &;

data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
part = partition[data]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7,
>      8}, {7, 8}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
tests = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[Mean[#], 1]] & /@ part
```

> {1.98568, 2.26188, 4.5443, 4.1307, 4.58325, 5.98513, 7.02065, 7.59776}

```
data2 = Min /@ Transpose[{data, tests}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 4.58325, 5.98513, 7, 7.59776}

```
part2 = partition @ data2
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 4.58325}, {4, 4.58325, 
>         5.98513}, {4.58325, 5.98513, 7}, {5.98513, 7, 7.59776}, {7, 
>         7.59776}}

**Note:** Whenever part `i` of `data` is replaced with, say, `xx`, appropriate parts of `part` are also replaced with `xx`.

```
i = 3;
modifieddata = ReplacePart[data, i -> xx]
```

> {1, 2, xx, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

```
modifiedpart = ReplacePart[part, {{i - 1, 3} -> xx, {i, 2} -> xx, {i + 1, 1} -> xx}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 2, xx}, {2, xx, 4}, {xx, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6,
>          7, 8}, {7, 8}}

Instead of using `ReplacePart` on `part` you can partition `modifieddata` using the function `partition` and get  the same result:

```
partition @ modifieddata == modifiedpart
```

> True

Comment: That is a very neat solution but it does not quite do what I need. I used `part=ReplacePart[etc]` in my code because `part` is input for the test, so elem. i+1 needs to be updated before the test uses it. As I said, it is a cursoring, not something done in parallel. I updated my OP with 'test=Mean[part[[i]]]` to make this clearer. Still, thank you very much!

Comment: @Titus, updated with your new example.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?
Here is the result after applying the operation to all elements

```
ClearAll[data, list, k, l]
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
l = Length@list;
data[x_] := Partition[x, 3, 1, {-2, 2}, {}]
Table[test = RandomReal[{1, 8}];
 If[list[[i]] > test, list = ReplacePart[list, i -> test]]; 
 data@list, {i, l}]

list
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 
>      7, 8}, {7, 8}},
>    {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 
>      6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}},
>    {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 
>      4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}},
>    {{1, 
>      2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3.51974}, {3, 3.51974, 5}, {3.51974, 5, 
>      6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}},
>    {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 
>      3.51974}, {3, 3.51974, 5}, {3.51974, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 
>      8}, {7, 8}},
>      {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3.51974}, {3, 3.51974, 
>      5}, {3.51974, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8}},
>    {{1, 2}, {1, 2,
>       3}, {2, 3, 3.51974}, {3, 3.51974, 5}, {3.51974, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 
>      6.08169}, {6, 6.08169, 8}, {6.08169, 8}},
>    {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 
>      3, 3.51974}, {3, 3.51974, 5}, {3.51974, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 6.08169}, {6,
>       6.08169, 5.86203}, {6.08169, 5.86203}}}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 3.51974, 5, 6, 6.08169, 5.86203}

Comment: Thank you very much, this does indeed wht I described but with one difference: Because part is actually input for the actual test (e.g. `test =Mean[part[[i]]]`), I need to Table a list at every iteration so that the i+1 element in part will have been updated before the cursoring reaches it. I updated the OP.

Comment: @Titus updated. Is that the output you want?